# What does Parity logs means?

Tags: parity, logs, terminology

Usually, Parity logs looks like:

```
2016-12-04 20:56:28  Syncing #2346672 6eb0…3382      2 blk/s   25 tx/s   0 Mgas/s   13529+    0 Qed   #2360201    0/ 8/25 peers     10 MiB db    6 MiB chain   50 MiB queue    2 MiB sync
2016-12-04 20:56:33  Syncing #2346682 732e…9811      1 blk/s   18 tx/s   0 Mgas/s   13518+    0 Qed   #2360201    0/ 8/25 peers     10 MiB db    5 MiB chain   50 MiB queue    2 MiB sync
2016-12-04 20:56:38  Syncing #2346703 743c…36b1      4 blk/s   12 tx/s   0 Mgas/s   13498+    0 Qed   #2360201    0/ 8/25 peers     10 MiB db    5 MiB chain   50 MiB queue    2 MiB sync
2016-12-04 20:56:48  Syncing #2346802 baa1…2f6b      9 blk/s   30 tx/s   0 Mgas/s   13399+    0 Qed   #2360201    0/ 8/25 peers      9 MiB db    6 MiB chain   50 MiB queue    2 MiB sync
```

Easy to guess, that

`2016-12-04 20:56:28` - timestamp

`Syncing #2346802` - syncing block #...

`6eb0…3382` - probably block's hash

`9 blk/s` - download speed, blocks per second

`12 tx/s` - download speed, transactions per second

Can you explain, what other columns mean?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your ideas for the first few fields are correct.

The remainder are as follows:

`0 Mgas/s` - million gas processed/s

`13399+` - unverified queue size

`0` - verified queue size

`#2360201` - last imported block number

`0/8/25 peers` - number of active peers / number of known peers / configured maximum number of peers (this can be configured up to 50)

`9 MiB db` - state database memory used

`6 MiB chain` - blockchain cache info memory used

`50 MiB queue` - queue memory used (contains information about the queued blocks)

`2 MiB sync` - sync memory used (contains information about the connected peers, last imported block, etc.)

I believe the stray `Qed` is actually a typo. It should be `qed`, which is an argument passed to the tracing to allow for the use of ["Panickers"](https://github.com/paritytech/parity/wiki/Coding-guide#panickers). It shouldn't be output by the logs.

The logs are created by the code in [`informant.rs`](https://github.com/paritytech/parity/blob/94e3a98524dc9f767e92a3817de18e22f7075588/parity/informant.rs#L126).

---

**Edit:**

As per the comments, it's far more likely that `Qed` stands for "queued".

Comment: Interesting! Now I am wondering what a verified queue is.

Comment: `Qed` is likely a shortening or typo for queued, the proceeding two numbers being the unverified/verified queue size

Comment: @Nick: Ah. That makes more sense - my idea was far too convoluted :-)

Comment: So what is one individual item being Queued? The verified queued does not match block # . looks like blk/s is blocks per second

Answer (score 3):

Here's a direct description from the online documentation: https://openethereum.github.io/FAQ#what-does-openethereums-command-line-output-mean